# How to use Schema.org VideoObject markup to use custom video player

Tags: flash, schema.org

I have a custom flash video player. I posted the player to Google plus(shared). I am using open graph method to post the player. I am getting video title, description, image posted to Google plus. But, the problem is, the video and the player is not loading instead its redirecting to other page.

I checked posting of video with YouTube and Vimeo from respective site. And the video is loading and playing fine there.

I searched for the solution and get this link for uploading/sharing/posting customized swf player : http://schema.org/VideoObject
But, I am not getting how to implement it.

Can anyone help me this out. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can review the Google [documentation and schema.org example for VideoObject](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2413309)